# i need to output all words matching in unix file

Tags: text-processing, awk

When i have this set of data in a unix text file named raw.txt

```
2020-05-28 08:00:32,360 | push_imgs | INFO | Pulled 950-09050294592-FACE.jpg
2020-05-28 08:00:32,373 | push_imgs | INFO | Pulled 950-09050294592-SIGNATURE.jpg
```

I only need to print the Date and the .jpg file. like the sample below

```
2020-05-28 950-09050294592-FACE.jpg
```

I currently have below script which will just get all lines with pulled and .jpg. i only need to print date and the .jpg file.

```
awk '/Pulled/&&/.jpg/' IGNORECASE=1 /home/user/rawfile.txt
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If all lines contain Pulled and .jpg as in the example then searching for this in the file is a waste of resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried printing the corresponding fields?

```
 awk '/Pulled/&&/.jpg/ { print ($1 $9);} ' IGNORECASE=1 yourfile
```

Comment: thanks a lot! u answered my question!!!! :))) God Bless and stay safe!

Comment: @Ralph If one of the answers solved your issue, please take a moment to [accept it](//$$SITEURL/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on [the checkmark on the left](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/203101). That will mark the question as answered and is the way that thanks are conveyed on the Stack Exchange sites.

Comment: olryt! thanks for the tip! i think i will learn a lot from this community! :D

Comment: `.` is a regexp metachar, ITYM `/\.jpg/` and you may also want a `$` at the end to anchor it. You also probably want `print $1, $9` instead of `print ($1 $9);`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all lines in the format shown in the question you can simply use `cut`

```
$ cut -d' ' -f 1,9 yourfile
2020-05-28 950-09050294592-FACE.jpg
2020-05-28 950-09050294592-SIGNATURE.jpg
```

If there are other lines as well you can filter with `egrep`

```
$ grep 'jpg[[:blank:]]*$' yourfile | cut -d' ' -f 1,9
$ grep -E 'Pulled .+jpg[[:blank:]]*$' yourfile | cut -d' ' -f 1,9
```

<sub>The `[[:blank:]]*$` matches the end of line even if there are spaces between `jpg` and the actual line end</sub>

or of course use the `awk` approach shown in another answer.

Comment: olryt! thanks for the tip! i think i will learn a lot from this community! :D